# Clone a selected row in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, clone

I am currently able to delete a selected row, and now I want to duplicate/clone the selected row. Sometimes adding rows to DataTables can be tricky because the pagination will not update, so clone and append.

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/30/

**jQuery**

```
var oTable;

    /* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
    $("#example tbody tr").click( function( e ) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        }
        else {
            oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }
    });


    /* Add a click handler for the delete row */
    $('#delete').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        if ( anSelected.length !== 0 ) {
            oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
        }
    } );


    /* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( );



/* Get the rows which are currently selected */
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    return oTableLocal.$('tr.row_selected');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to respect paging of jquery datatables the clone method should be calling the fnAddData function,

```
$('#clone').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        console.log(anSelected);
        var data=[];
        $(anSelected).find('td').each(function(){data.push($(this).text());});
        oTable.fnAddData( data );
    } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/32/

You need to add the click listener for selecting to these new rows as well.

For example,

```
$('#clone').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        var data=[];
        $(anSelected).find('td').each(function(){data.push($(this).html());});
        var row=oTable.fnAddData( data );//returns the index of the row added
        $(oTable.fnGetNodes(row)).click( function( e ) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        }
        else {
            oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }
    });
    } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/33/

Comment: minor problem here. I didn't add this in my jsfiddle (because I didn't think it would make a difference) but the first td in every row has icons. When cloning (using the code above) the icons are not cloned along with the rest of the data.

Comment: Got it, .html() rather than .text(). Thanks again.

Comment: @triplethreat77 if you need to manipulate the added row i.e. add a click listener you can get it by calling fnGetNodes with param the index of the row added. The index is returned from the function fnAddData. I'll update the answer to also demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented using the `.clone()` jQuery, see: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/31/)

```
$('#clone').click(function(){
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );

        anSelected.clone().insertAfter( $("table").find("tr").last());
        $("table").find("tr").last().removeClass("row_selected");
    });
```

Hope this help

Comment: The fiddle doesn't quite work. The newly added row cannot be selected.